# Build small sdk with typescript to one js file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to build small sdk library written in typescript. My idea is to create project that will contains many ts files which compile to one js and my library can be access like **foo.bar.myPublicClasses**

Biggest remark I don't want to use it on simple html pages, my environment is Dynamics CRM, so including JavaScript isn't done in normal html script include tag, and loading JavaScript is done in asynchronous with build framework of Dynamics CRM. So that's why I need to bundle my library to one files. 
So to summaries I need one bundled js file without any dependencies with d.ts file too so it can be reused on other typescript files.
Additional to run my js code from Dynamics CRM I need any global function, my approach would be some static function on class foo.bar.mylibrary.sdk.create()

My Project structure could look like this:

```
 src/
 |-bundle.ts
 |-classes/
 | |-classA.ts
 | |-classB.ts
 | 
 |-interfaces/
 | |-IInterface1.ts
 | -IInterface2.ts
 |
 |-Helpers/
 | |-HelperA.ts
 | |-HelperA.ts
 |
 dist/
 | -myLibrary.js
```

I would like to have .ts files more like I would write my C# code one file per class etc.

**Version 1**
My initial approach was to use namespace but I'm not sure if that would be best way to do it in long run of project. in that apporach I write all ts files in my namespace only one bad smell for me is that in combined js file each ts file would write

```
//a.ts
namespace foo.bar.mylibrary{
    class a {
        isOk:boolean;
    }
    export class b {
        constructor(){
            let test = new a();
            test.isOk = false;
        }
    }
}
//b.ts
namespace foo.bar.mylibrary{
    export class sdk{
        public isStart:boolean;
        public static Create(){
            //initialize my sdk
        }
    }
}
```

compile to

```
"use strict";
// b.ts
var foo;
(function (foo) {
    var bar;
    (function (bar) {
        var mylibrary;
        (function (mylibrary) {
            var a = (function () {
                function a() {
                }
                return a;
            }());
            var b = (function () {
                function b() {
                    var test = new a();
                    test.isOk = false;
                }
                return b;
            }());
            mylibrary.b = b;
        })(mylibrary = bar.mylibrary || (bar.mylibrary = {}));
    })(bar = foo.bar || (foo.bar = {}));
})(foo || (foo = {}));
var foo;
(function (foo) {
    var bar;
    (function (bar) {
        var mylibrary;
        (function (mylibrary) {
            var sdk = (function () {
                function sdk() {
                }
                sdk.Create = function () {
                    //initialize my sdk
                };
                return sdk;
            }());
            mylibrary.sdk = sdk;
        })(mylibrary = bar.mylibrary || (bar.mylibrary = {}));
    })(bar = foo.bar || (foo.bar = {}));
})(foo || (foo = {}));
```

Maybe there is better way to compile those ts files.

my tsconfig contains module - commonjs, outputfile - myLibrary.js

**Version 2**
According to typescript documentation it would be better now to use  external modules, but I'm not sure if compiled js is what I would see not exported classes are compiled to simple var object and exported class are in defined functions.

```
//a.ts
    class a {
        isOk:boolean;
    }
    export class b {
        constructor(){
            let test = new a();
            test.isOk = false;
        }
    }

//b.ts

    export class sdk{
        public isStart:boolean;
        public static Create(){
            //initialize my sdk
        }
    }
//build.ts
export {sdk} from "./src/b";
```

compile to

```
define(["require", "exports", "./src/classb"], function (require, exports, classb_1) {
    "use strict";
    function __export(m) {
        for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
    }
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    // export * from "./src/classa";
    __export(classb_1);
});
```

And then I need to bundle my required modules but I don't know how to do it in proper way.

my tsconfig contains module - amd, outputfile - myLibrary.js

I assume to accomplish my library I should gulp or some other toolkit, but can anyone give me some hints or how to do it?

Comment: Is your output.js file being loaded client-side on a Dynamics CRM form or is it running server-side via Node (or other)?

Comment: only on client-side

Answer (score 0):

this is my tsconfig.json and it only transpiles to a single js file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "../public/js/yourfile.js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Like I written in my question and posted example I know how to compile ts into one js with tsconfig, but it works almost  perfect only with version 1 when I use namespaces, with external modules it's compiled to only exported class as define.